# Insert JavaScript variable into JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to insert a js variable into json (to show a message on slack).
I have tested this :

```
 "fields":[  
     {  
        "title": "Reported by:",
        "value": "'+ user + '",
        "short": "false"
     },
```

but it doesn't work and show me this :

> Reported by:
>
> '+ user +'

**Thanks you !**

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you should be doing something like:

`"value": "'" + user + "'",`

Before user was still part of the string expression.

Comment: It doesn't work but thanks for your help.
Here is the code is use :
`[  
   {  
      "pretext": "",
      "text": "test",
      "color": "#F35A00",
      "fields": [  
         {  
            "title": "Reported by :",
            "value": "'" + user + "'",
            "short": "false"
         },
         {  
            "title": "Project:",
            "value": "No",
            "short": "false"
         }
      ]
   }
]
`

Answer (score 1):

This is called string concatenation:

```
 {  
    "title": "Reported by:",
    "value": "'" + user + "'",
    "short": "false"
 }
```

The `value` will produce a string with the combined values, such as if `user` were a string value of `"Jamen"`, the concatenated value of `value` would be `"'Jamen'"`